# PostgreSQL table not being created in Flask app - works locally but not in production

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm building a PostgreSQL database in production for the first time and haven't been able to initialize the DB.

```
class User(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.String, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    main_domain = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=True)
    subdomains = relationship('Subdomain', backref='user', lazy=True)
    
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % self.id 

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    db.create_all()
    app.run()
```

The code fails checking if the user already exists in the login app route, claiming: relation "users" does not exist. The raw SQL code is SELECT users.id AS users_id, users.main_domain AS users_main_domain, users.email AS users_email

```
    user_id = me.data.get('id') # localId
    # username = me.data.get('displayName')
    email = me.data.get('email')

    if user_id and email: # and username 
        user = User.query.get(user_id)
        if not user:
            user = User(id=user_id, email=email) 
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()
        session['user_id'] = user.id
        return redirect(url_for('account'))
    else:
        return 'Error: Missing user data'
```

I know the issue isn't connection (I've tried two SQL hosting providers) and I've troubleshooted different ways of running db.create_all(). Creating the database works fine locally on SQLite. What could the issue be?

Comment: [create_all](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all) creates the tables in a database. For Postgres you will need to create the database outside of SQLAlchemy before you run the `create_all`. You don't need to do that with SQLite as it is a single file that is created as part of the [URL](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/engines.html#database-urls).